# Slow loop using GCD

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I've to run many packages but also some method (70 methods + 40 packages), and I am building _myArray based on what user have selected in the app interface.
This is because I can not know what that user will select before press the "start" button, and the app requires that all things follow a predetermined order (_myArray was sorted). The app support OSX since 10.7

```
-(void)package01 {
}

-(void)package02 {
}

.....

-(void)package40 {

    // also tried with NSTask, but is slow exactly as NSAppleScript (so guess that this is not the problem)

    NSString* package = [_pathToPkg stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"40.pkg"];
    NSAppleScript* runpkg;
    NSString *command = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/usr/sbin/installer -pkg %@ -target %@", package, _targetOBJ];

    runpkg = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                                    @"do shell script \"%@\"", command]];

    [runpkg executeAndReturnError: nil];
}

-(void)oneOfMyMethod {
dispatch_async(_myQueue,
               ^{
                   // some operation
                   dispatch_async(_mymainQueue, ^{/*updating interface here*/});
               });

dispatch_async(_myQueue,
               ^{
                   // more operation
                   dispatch_async(_mymainQueue, ^{/*updating interface here*/});
               });

dispatch_async(_myQueue,
               ^{
                   // ++ operation
                   dispatch_async(_mymainQueue, ^{/*updating interface here*/});
               });


// Here I'm calling the problematic Method:
[self runPackageOrMethod:^(BOOL finished) {
    if(finished){
        [self doOther];
    }
}];
```

}

```
// this is pratically the core of the app...
- (void) runPackageOrMethod:(completion) compblock{

    _pathToPkg = @"path/to/the/folder/that/contain/packages";


    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    @try {
        for (NSString *method in _myArray) {
                    NSArray *descriptions;
                    descriptions = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[METHOD_DESCRIPTION allKeys]]; // Another array that I use to display some info about running pkg or method

                    dispatch_group_async(group,_myQueue, ^ {
                        dispatch_async(_mymainQueue, ^{
                            if ([descriptions containsObject:method] && ![[METHOD_DESCRIPTION objectForKey:method] isEqualToString:@"MUTE"]) {
                                [_displayStore appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n- %@\n", [METHOD_DESCRIPTION objectForKey:method]]  attributes:_dispAttr]];
                                [_display scrollToEndOfDocument:self];
                            }
                        });
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
                        dispatch_async(_mymainQueue, ^{[self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(method)  withObject:nil];});
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
                    });
            }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", [exception description]);
    }
    @finally {
        compblock(YES);
    }
}
```

The code is particularly slow while running a packages (always more than 30)..

Any Ideas on how solve?

Comment: @Hela Vora, I hope that GCD or GDC no make the difference since in Italy is "Gran Dispaccio Centrale" :), but no supposition about the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this will help but Apple's installer binary at /usr/sbin/installer does not install more than one package at a time. So even though you have everything dispatched on a queue the underlying tool that gets invoked serializes it and installs one package at time.

So if you have 30 packages (or .pkgs) the installer tool will spend a lot of time unarchiving it and installing it.

I don't think you can get around it without writing your own version of the "installer" tool that does what you want.

Comment: The code is inside a "for" loop, and this is add the methods to the queue (that run packages or not). But this does not means that every item in the queue runs one after the other, but each is executed only after the end of the previous one? Thank you for responding, I'm thinking about what you said.

Comment: Yea so lets say I have 4 packages. Using dispatch queue and NSTask or AppleScript to call the installer tool and install them. All for blocks invoke the installer command line tool. But the installer tool internally has a queue that just installs one package at a time. So If a package is installing and you try to install another one using that tool, you will get a "waiting for other installations to finish" message from the installer. You can run the installer with the -verboseR option if you want.

Comment: Ha, the cat is cooked! Now you have opened my mind.. but now I cry because how to solve now is more complicated. any proposing to modify the code?

Comment: Haha I feel your pain. There is no real easy way around it. If you want to use apple's installer mechanism then you have to live with this. But really you shouldn't be installing 30-40 pkgs. You can easily merge all of them into a mpkg or even better try to merge all your pkgs into a single pkg. The fewer the better. The alternative is to write your own version of the "installer" tool.

Comment: You can do it on the fly but then you will have to sign the mpkg on the fly as well. I am not sure if you want to ship your code with a certificate and private key. Without signing you cannot install the mpkg (Technically you can but i don't think thats what you want).

Comment: Before try that, I'll made a test: alway run all methods! The app in fact must run alway package 01 and package 40. The idea is to run all in cascade...the first method call the second and so on. But only if the operation is contained in "_myarray" the task will be performed, otherwise simply move on to the next method!....